# UISeachBar detect when user press Search button

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I try to get notification when the `Search` button is clicked in the keyboard in the `UISearchBar` with this :

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

        return YES;
    }
```

But this method won't call when I press the Search button.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Have you tried this delegate

Objective-C:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

Swift:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

See the documentation for any searchbar delegates.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate

Comment: Can i get in this method the text that is in the Textview in the UISearchBar?

Comment: You should implement this method to begin the search. Use the 'text' property of the search bar(UISearchBar) to get the text. You can also send becomeFirstResponder to the search bar to begin editing programmatically.

Comment: Yup.. like @hpiOSCoder said get the text from the searchbar.  searchBar.text will yield you the value.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something upon 'search' button get clicked then, Try this method

> - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

Tells the delegate that the search button was tapped.

Answer (score 4):

You've to set the searchBar delegate first.
In the `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.searchBar.delegate = self
```

then `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.X:

1) Set delegate:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

2) Add function:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```